# How to get online data in Android App?

Tags: android, html, json, parsing, jsoup

I would like to get some data (SAT/ACT scores for example) from this webpage: http://www.parchment.com/c/college/college-1474-University-of-Michigan---Ann-Arbor.html and have the data shown in my Android application. What would be the best way to do this. If possible, please provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial, it uses Jsoup library (HTML parser) to get the HTML and parse it to access data in elements using CSS selectors.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/